# Why Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','?

Tags: google-analytics, next.js

Why I'm getting this error. I have this code in my Nextjs app Head component.

```
{/* <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --> */}
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-X" />
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('set', {'user_id', '${userData?.id}'})
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-X', {
      page_path: window.location.pathname,
    }); `,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Check this line `gtag('set', {'user_id', '${userData?.id}'})`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to give an answer to the question that otherwise seems unresolved.

This line:

```
gtag('set', {'user_id', '${userData?.id}'})
```

should be:

```
gtag('set', {'user_id' : '${userData?.id}'})
```